# How to add custom music?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've heard that you can add your own custom music to be played through the iDroid if you have the PC version of MGSV. If it's possible, how do you do it? Can it be done on the console versions?

Comment: you might wanna take a look at that http://www.gamepur.com/guide/20188-mgs-v-phantom-pain-how-add-custom-music-idroid.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding custom music is only possible in the PC release of Metal Gear Solid 5.

To add your custom music, copy your audio files to the `CustomSoundtrack` within your Metal Gear Solid 5 folder (defaults to `C:\Programs (x86)\Steam\Steamapps\common\MGS_TPP`) and these will be picked up in game.

Comment: Do you have any idea for consoles too? i did some research but didn't find anything consistent, it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: @JohnnyBgud, you could just run the Spotify app in the background. Not quite the same... but at least you can listen to what you want while you play console.